# $L$-$S$ coupling with more than two electrons in the last shell

Tags: angular-momentum, atomic-physics, orbitals

Is there a easy way to calculate all the terms for complicate configurations with more than two electrons in the last shell?

If I try to find the terms in $L$-$S$ coupling $[Ar]3d^3$ or $[Ar]3d^5$ looks very hard. When I have just two electrons in the last level there are rules that make easier to compute it and respect Pauli, for example, I can just do $S=|s_1-s_2|, ..., s_1+s_2$ and $L=|l_1-l_2|,...,l_1+l_2$ and the only terms that satisfy Pauli are the ones with $L+S=$even number

In the first example $[Ar]3d^3$ I would try to do it in this way: First calculate the terms for the first two electrons and find

$$ 3d^2 \to S=0,1 \quad L=0,1,2,3,4 $$

Applying Pauli

$$ S=0, L=0 \to \quad  ^1S \quad \quad \quad \quad S=1, L=0 \to \quad  Impossible $$

$$ S=0, L=1 \to \quad  Impossible \quad \quad \quad \quad S=1, L=1 \to \quad ^3P  $$

$$ S=0, L=2 \to \quad  ^1D \quad \quad \quad \quad S=1, L=2 \to \quad  Impossible $$

$$ S=0, L=3 \to \quad  Impossible \quad \quad \quad \quad S=1, L=3 \to \quad ^3F  $$

$$ S=0, L=4 \to \quad  ^1G \quad \quad \quad \quad S=1, L=4 \to \quad  Impossible $$

So I have this terms $^1S, ^3P, ^1D, ^3F, ^1G$. Now I should do the same for the third electron with each of this term
$^1S + 3d  \quad \to \quad L_1=0, S_1=0, l_2=2, s_2=1/2  \quad \to \quad L=2, S=1/2$
$^3P + 3d  \quad \to \quad L_1=1, S_1=1, l_2=2, s_2=1/2  \quad \to \quad L=1,2,3; S=1/2,3/2$
$^1D + 3d  \quad \to \quad L_1=2, S_1=0, l_2=2, s_2=1/2  \quad \to \quad L=0,1,2,3,4; S=1/2$
$^3F + 3d  \quad \to \quad L_1=3, S_1=1, l_2=2, s_2=1/2  \quad \to \quad L=1,2,3,4,5; S=1/2,3/2$
$^1G + 3d  \quad \to \quad L_1=4, S_1=0, l_2=2, s_2=1/2  \quad \to \quad L=2,3,4,5,6; S=1/2$

But now, how can I identify the terms that I have to delete to respect Pauli?

Answer (score 1):

This will not be very satisfactory answer but yes there is way, which requires the use of [Young diagrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young_tableau) or partitions to label representations of the permutation group.

When you have 2 particles, the $S$ or $L$ states can be only symmetric or antisymmetric.  It's then a matter of combining the proper states.

When you have 3 or more particles, you can have states with *mixed* symmetry.  For instance, with three spin-1/2 particles, you have $S=3/2$ states with are fully symmetric: the permutation symmetry is labelled by the partition $\{3\}$ In addition, there are *two* sets of $S=1/2$ states with mixed symmetry the permutation symmetry is labelled by the partition $\{2,1\}$.  It's no so easy to draw Young diagrams with this editor so I will dispense with that part.

In an obvious notation, the two different $S=1/2, M_s=1/2$ states are
\begin{align}
    \vert\textstyle\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{2}\rangle_1&=
    \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\vert+\rangle_1\vert-\rangle_2\vert+\rangle_3-
\vert-\rangle_1\vert+\rangle_2\vert+\rangle_3\right), \tag{1} \\
\vert \textstyle\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{2}\rangle_2&=
-\frac{2}{\sqrt{6}}\vert +\rangle_1\vert+\rangle_2\vert-\rangle_3
+\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}\vert +\rangle_1\vert-\rangle_2\vert+\rangle_3
+\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}\vert -\rangle_1\vert+\rangle_2\vert+\rangle_3 \, .\tag{2}
\end{align}
You will notice that the state in (1) is antisymmetric w/r to permutation of spins 1 and 2, but if you permute spins 1 and 3, or spins 2 and 3, it does not come back to itself: rather it goes to a linear combination of the state (1) and (2).  The state of (2) does not have any obvious permutation symmetry but again if you permute any two spins, you will get a linear combination of (1) and (2).

The same occurs when you combine multiple states with the *same* $\ell$: some of the possible total $L$ values will be repeated, and for these values of $L$ the states will have mixed symmetry.  To best understand the permutation symmetries of your complete set of $3$ $\ell=2$ states requires plethysms and Schur functions (wiki is not helpful for either), or a *really* painful hand calculation.  After some work I did find the following:

- The set of fully symmetric states (partition $\{3,0\}$) contains states with $L=6,4,3,2,0$,
- The set of partially symmetric states (partition $\{2,1\}$) contains states with $L=5,4,3,2,2,1$ ($L=2$ is repeated twice),
- The set of fully antisymmetric states (partition $\{1,1,1\}$) contains states with $L=3$ and $L=1$.

Now there's a rule which comes up when studying the permutation group, and it is that to construct a fully symmetric state you must combine states with the same type of permutation symmetry, while to construct fully antisymmetric states you must combine states with conjugate permutation symmetries.  I don't want to get into the definition of conjugate symmetries but suffice it to say that, to construct fully antisymmetric states you would need to combine:

1. the possible values of $L$ for partition $\{1,1,1\}$ with the possible values of $S$ for partition $\{3\}$: thus here you get values of $J$ in
   $L\otimes S=3\otimes 3/2$ and $1\otimes 3/2$.
2. the possible values of $L$ for partition $\{2,1\}$ with the possible values of $S$ for partition $\{2,1\}$: thus here you get two values of $J$ (one for each set of spin states with $S=1/2$) in
   $5\otimes\frac{1}{2}, 4\otimes\frac{1}{2}, 3\otimes\frac{1}{2}$, a total of 4 sets $2\otimes\frac{1}{2}$ since $L=2$ appear twice, and $S=1/2$ appear twice, and finally a pair for $1\otimes\frac{1}{2}$.
3. Because there are not $S$ states labelled by the partition $\{1,1,1\}$, it is not possible to construct antisymmetric states with value of $L$ for the partition $\{3\}$.  Thus in particular no states with $J=13/2$ can be fully antisymmetric; the largest $J$ value will be 11/2, and will occur in combining $L=5$ with $S=1/2$ states.